# How to get jobid from inside job in php-resque?

Tags: php, php-resque

I'm having first steps with php-resque https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque .
Anybody knows how can I get jobid inside Job Class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the id/token with:
    $this->job->payload["id"];